# Windows secure file copy between servers

Tags: windows, security, copying

I have looked a bunch of questions on here somewhat related to what Im trying to do. Maybe windows has just not gotten on the security train yet.

Im not trying to use sftp, or WinSCP or SSH

Basically what i need to do is copy files from \server1\xxx\ to \server2\yyy

This will have to be done everyday.

I cannot install FTP on either of the servers.

Server 2012 r2 is the OS

However there are concerns about data in transit.

Is there a native way in windows to copy files securely?

Robocopy works fines for what I want however I dont see a way to secure the files from point A to point B

Comment: vpn between each site ?

Comment: You probably want to look at IPsec Policies for securing the communication between the two servers.

Comment: Did you actually do any research on this for yourself?  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn551363(v=ws.11).aspx

Comment: @JamesSnell yes I did and thank you for asking so nicely

Comment: As @joeqwerty mentioned, consider IPsec. [My blog](https://securitytidbits.wordpress.com/tag/ipsec/) has some netsh commands to quickly get you started.

Comment: @user2320464 Thank you I will try that out, if it works I will let you know.

Comment: Here's the step by step to securing 2 2012r2 machines with powershell:  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831807(v=ws.11).aspx

Comment: I'd also be curious as to what the concerns are for in transit data, MITM, simply looking to have the traffic encrypted etc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

SMB is the protocol windows uses for sharing and it supports encryption for content in transit.  It's always handy to include this term in any searches you do related to windows file shares.

> SMB Encryption provides end-to-end encryption of SMB data and protects data from eavesdropping occurrences on untrusted networks.
>   *Source [Technet: SMB security enhancements](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn551363(v=ws.11).aspx)*

The link also describes how to enable the functionality for either a single share or a whole server using AES CCM encryption either via the UI or Server Manager.

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted - for most applications AES encryption is just fine